# PHP - getting last statements PK ID to use in second function Insert statement

Tags: php, mysql, function, pdo

**Duplicate Edit**: This question is different because I'm trying to return a specific value, the primary key ID to be used in another functions `INSERT` statement as a foreign key, within the same action. The "duplicate" question does not answer this, rather it only shows how to get a return value from a function. Not how to get it and insert it correctly in another functions prepare statement. Which I wasn't sure I was doing correctly.

I have two tables, `orders` and `customers` that are to have data inserted from one form within the same action. The `orders` table has a primary key = `orderID` which also needs to be added into the `customers` table.

**DB Relationship Diagram**
[image: Relationship Diagram]

I can upload the data to the `orders` table without a problem, but the second query function to the customers table does nothing. I'm pretty sure it's due to the foreign key constraint I've set. I've done some research and realize I need to get the foreign key id, possibly using `$mysqli->insert_id` or `PDO::lastInsertId`, but I'm lost as to how to use it with my current functions.

**index.php**

```
$product = $_POST['product'];
$fName = $_POST['fName'];
$lName = $_POST['lName'];
$address = $_POST['address'];
$address2 = $_POST['address2'];
$city = $_POST['city'];
$state = $_POST['state'];
$zip = $_POST['zip'];
$country = $_POST['country'];
$phoneNumber = $_POST['phoneNumber'];
$email = $_POST['email'];
/* Functions */
order_Data ($db, $product, $fName, $lName, $email);
// Need to have orderID  from ^ table used in order_custData sql statement
order_custData($db, $orderID, $fName, $lName, $address, $address2, $city, $state, $zip, $country, $phoneNumber, $email);
```

**functions.php**

```
<?php 

/**  Order Data Function
 */
function order_Data($db, $product, $fName, $lName, $email) {
    try {
        $sql = "INSERT INTO orders SET product = :product, fName = :fName, lName = :lName, email = :email";
        $ps = $db->prepare($sql);
        $ps->bindValue(':product', $product);
        $ps->bindValue(':fName', $fName);
        $ps->bindValue(':lName', $lName);
        $ps->bindValue(':email', $email);
        $ps->execute();
        return $orderID = $db->lastInsertId();
    } catch (PDOException $e) {
        die("Sorry, There was a problem order table.");
    }
}

/**  Customer Purchase Information Function
 * @param $orderID -- I need to insert the orderID from orders table?
 */
function order_custData($db, $orderID, $fName, $lName, $address, $address2, $city, $state, $zip, $country, $phoneNumber, $email) {
    try {
        $sql = "INSERT INTO customers SET  orderID = :orderID, fName = :fName, lName = :lName, address = :address, address2 = :address2,city = :city, state = :state, zip = :zip, country = :country, phoneNumber = :phoneNumber, email = :email";
        $ps = $db->prepare($sql);
        $ps->bindValue(':orderID', $orderID); // Foreign key from orders table
        $ps->bindValue(':fName', $fName);
        $ps->bindValue(':lName', $lName);
        $ps->bindValue(':address', $address);
        $ps->bindValue(':address2', $address2);
        $ps->bindValue(':city', $city);
        $ps->bindValue(':state', $state);
        $ps->bindValue(':zip', $zip);
        $ps->bindValue(':country', $country);
        $ps->bindValue(':phoneNumber', $phoneNumber);
        $ps->bindValue(':email', $email);
        return $ps->execute();
    } catch (PDOException $e) {
        die("Sorry, There was a problem with the customer table!");
    }
}
?>
```

Now the `$orderID` and `:orderID` IN THE `order_custData` function are just there for me as a visual representation to figure out the problem. I wasn't try to execute the sql statement with it originally. However, anything I've tried seems to throw errors `underfined variable` or fatal calls to the prepare function of the first function.

Thank you for your time.

Comment: You're returning the value (though it should just be `return $db->lastInsertId();`) so just assign it to the right variable, eg `$orderID = order_Data($db, $product, $fName, $lName, $email);`

Comment: After spending 5 hours trying to figure this out, it was so simple. Thank you.

Comment: Shouldn't **orders** table have *customerID* as foreign key instead of using *orderID* as foreign key for **customer** table? Since, one customer probably can have more than one order. Just a thought!

Comment: @BivekSingh Yes, you're absolutely right.This is something I'll fix. Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The utility function `order_Data()` already returns the ID:

```
…
return $orderID = $db->lastInsertId();
```

(Rewrite to `return $db->lastInsertId();`, though.)

Simply carry the return value by assigning to a variable:

```
$orderID = order_Data ($db, $product, $fName, $lName, $email);
order_custData($db, $orderID, $fN …);
```

Comment: @Phil Good catch. Edited.

Answer (score 1):

> Try this. Simply carry the return value by assigning to a variable

```
<?php
require_once ("models/dbConn.php");
require_once ("models/functions.php");
$action = $_REQUEST['action'];
if ($action == NULL || empty($action)):
    $action = '';
endif;
include_once ("views/header.php");
switch ($action) :
    case '':
        include ("views/main.php");
        break;
    case 'checkoutCart':
        // Once form button is clicked action = completePurchase
        include ("views/checkout.php");
        break;
    case 'completePurchase':
        $product = $_POST['product'];
        $fName = $_POST['fName'];
        $lName = $_POST['lName'];
        $address = $_POST['address'];
        $address2 = $_POST['address2'];
        $city = $_POST['city'];
        $state = $_POST['state'];
        $zip = $_POST['zip'];
        $country = $_POST['country'];
        $phoneNumber = $_POST['phoneNumber'];
        $email = $_POST['email'];
        /* Functions */
```

> $orderID = order_Data ($db, $product, $fName, $lName, $email);

```
        // Need to have orderID  from ^ table used in order_custData sql statement
        order_custData($db, $orderID, $fName, $lName, $address, $address2, $city, $state, $zip, $country, $phoneNumber, $email);
        include ("views/complete.php");
        break;
endswitch;
include_once ("views/footer.php");
?>
```

Answer (score 1):

Your `order_Data()` function is returning the Order Id, but you are not assigning the the return value in `index.php` to `$objectID`.

I.e. Change this...

```
order_Data ($db, $product, $fName, $lName, $email);
```

... to this ...

```
$orderID = order_Data ($db, $product, $fName, $lName, $email);
```

I recommending checking your error reporting level for PHP on your development environment to include notices, as PHP will have triggered a notice for use of an undefined variable.